# add all results from for loop and echo it

Tags: php, for-loop

So I have this code:

```
<?php
for ($x=1; $x<=1000; $x++)
{

    if ($x % 15 == 0 || $x % 26 == 0)
    {
        echo $x;
        echo "<br \>";
    }
}
?>
```

This code will output all numbers divisible by 15 or 26. But what I really want is to add up all the results and echo it. So what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `by 15 and 26` conflict with `$x % 15 == 0 || $x % 26 == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
for ($x=1; $x<=1000; $x++)
{
    if ($x % 15 == 0 || $x % 26 == 0)
    {
        $sum += $x;
        // echo $x;
        // echo "<br \>";
    }
}
echo $sum. "<br\>";
?>
```

Comment: it still echoes the numbers divisible by 15 and 26. i only want to echo its total which is 51261.

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer, just commented the two `echo line`.

Comment: Any further question please feel free to comment here.

Comment: By the way, you want `all numbers divisible by 15 and 26`, but in your code, `$x % 15 == 0 || $x % 26 == 0`, which means `all numbers divisible by 15` **or** `26`.

Comment: OK. sorry for that. i think that confused you guys. i already edited it. thanks again.